# My flair doesn't have my new winter hat

Tags: bug, winter-bash, flair

I'll put it simple:

I am using the new winter bash hats:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1862812/nikolay-kostov?tab=profile

but my flair doesn't have it:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1862812.png?theme=clean

[image]

Comment: I don't think hats are supposed to show up in the flair.

Comment: You need to do something similar as is proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271899/158100)

Comment: Why do I get downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, hats have never shown up in the flair. You might want to post a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), although I suspect it won't be implemented for something that is only relevant for a small amount of time.

Also, the flair is a simple image - and thus, to show hats properly (I.e. when wearing a hat on toip off one's avatar), either the flair would have to grow vertically, which would break existing layouts, or the image would have to shrink, which would look ugly.